# Scrollable table with fixed header using CSS

Tags: css

I try to make a large table scrollable in two axis with a fixed header. What is the simplest way? I tried it with CSS only but my problem is the vertical scrollbar is hidden when the horizontal scroll bar is on the left side:

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vpm6nte2/1/)

```css
table,
tr td,
tr th {
  border: 1px solid grey
}

div.table-holder {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 17px)
}

td,
th {
  width: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-holder">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Gaga001</td>
        <td>Gaga002</td>
        <td>Gaga003</td>
        <td>Gaga004</td>
        <td>Gaga005</td>
        <td>Gaga006</td>
        <td>Gaga007</td>
        <td>Gaga008</td>
        <td>Gaga009</td>
        <td>Gaga010</td>
        <td>Gaga011</td>
        <td>Gaga012</td>
        <td>Gaga013</td>
        <td>Gaga014</td>
        <td>Gaga015</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>003</td>
        <td>004</td>
        <td>005</td>
        <td>006</td>
        <td>007</td>
        <td>008</td>
        <td>009</td>
        <td>010</td>
        <td>011</td>
        <td>012</td>
        <td>013</td>
        <td>014</td>
        <td>015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>002</td>
        <td>003</td>
        <td>004</td>
        <td>005</td>
        <td>006</td>
        <td>007</td>
        <td>008</td>
        <td>009</td>
        <td>010</td>
        <td>011</td>
        <td>012</td>
        <td>013</td>
        <td>014</td>
        <td>015</td>
      </tr>
      [...]
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas to fix that or other suggestions to solve that problem in CSS? I do not want to include additional frameworks...

Comment: Can you use javascript solutions?

Comment: Yes, there is probably no other way...
Do you have an idea for a simple JS solution?